# What is the recommended Size of data for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have around 500-600 Kb of images and data on a plist for an iphone application i created. I am not sure if this is recommended or not. Would anyone know if there is an ideal or reasonable limit for data in iOS apps?

Comment: My rule of thumb would be: if the app still runs as fast as you'd like it to and the amount of data loaded doesn't cause your app to crash, the amount of data loaded is "reasonable"

Comment: The limit for installation of a binary over wireless (cellular/3g/4g/etc) is 50 Mb for the app bundle now, so its really a matter of choice.

Comment: That's close to nothing compared to what you'd have if you made a 3D game. You're way in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5.0 and below allows for up to 20MB downloads over 3G.
iOS 5.1 and above allows for up to 50MB downloads over 3G.

Your app can theoretically be any size you want it to be and it will download over WIFI, although Apple may contact you if your app exceeds 200MB.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit in the air download of 50MB (recently increased from 20MB). If you reach this limit your app won't be downloadable from 3G connections (only through wifi).

iPhone users are used to big downloads, so I don't think you should worry too much about any other limit.

Comment: Note that your users will need to upgrade to iOS 5.1 to be able to download 50MB apps over 3G.

Comment: I'm still on iOS 5.0.1 and I can download apps greater than 20MB over 3G